# Swift Popover closing when touching background

Tags: swift, uiview, popover

I have a popover that is being called and I want the only way to close the popover is by clicking the Close button, not by taping on the background. Currently my code to launch the popover is like this:

```
 let popover = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverVC") as! PopOverViewController

        popover.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popover.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self as? UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate


        popover.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        popover.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)

        popover.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)

        popoverPresentationController?.passthroughViews = nil



        dimView.isHidden = false

        popover.dimView = self.dimView

        self.present(popover, animated: false)
```

I have a UIview in the background that I use to dim the background when the popover comes up but when you tap on the background, it closes the popover. How can I keep the popover open? I thought the `popoverPresentationController?.passthroughViews = nil` was supposed to resolve this but it hasn't.

**EDIT:**

Adding my PopOverViewController Class:

```
    class PopOverViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {


    var dimView:UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {

        print ("test")

        return false
    }


    @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {

        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

        dimView?.isHidden = true


    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see your PopOverViewController class?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the delegate of the presentation controller. You're already assigning `self`, just implement the below delegate method.

```
extension SelfsType: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {
       /* This disables the automatic dismissal, but you can make it conditional, too. Such as if the user entered enough information, etc */
       return false
    }
}
```

Where `SelfsType` is the class of `self` as used in the context of

```
popover.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self as? UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
```

Your code doesn't include that.

Comment: I tried adding `func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool return false}`  to my popover view controller and it didn't work. Tapping background still closes the popover.

Comment: Does the delegate method actually get called? (put a breakpoint or print statement to ensure its called)

Comment: I put a print in there and its not getting called.

Comment: @Martheli then you are not setting the delegate properly.

Comment: Change this `self as? UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` to `self as! UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` and see if your code crashes.

Comment: I updated my edit to include the new code changes that still does not work.

Comment: That is wrong, you need to put the entire code block I gave you in the calling VC, replace SelfsType with the type of the calling view controller.

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify where the code belongs.